# Getting exceptions "Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError " when running a Java agent code

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, java-8

I am trying to write a sample java bytecode instrumentation with java agent . I am doing with **normal command line** and with out maven .

This is the my folder structure :

```
--- bin
--- lib  ---> /javassist-3.22.0-GA 
--- META_INF --> MANIFEST.MF
--- src -- > org/springframework/aop/framework/ .java files
--- .classpath
--- .project
```

MANIFEST.MF file contain :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: Cycle
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_121
premain-class: org.springframework.aop.framework.DurationAgent
Created-By: vkp
```

And in eclipse `.classpath` contain following libraries

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/kp/javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/antlr-2.7.7.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/aopalliance-1.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.48.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/bcprov-jdk15on-1.48.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/cglib-nodep-2.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/com.springsource.com.ibm.websphere.uow-6.0.2.17.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/com.springsource.commonj-1.1.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/commons-codec-1.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/commons-collections-3.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/commons-io-1.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/commons-lang-2.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/commons-net-3.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/db2jcc_license_cisuz-4.8.87.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/db2jcc_license_cu-4.8.87.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/db2jcc4-4.8.87.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/dom4j-1.6.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/easymock-3.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/freemarker-2.3.16.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/grammatica-1.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/gson-2.3.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/hibernate-annotations-3.5.6-Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/hibernate-core-3.5.6-Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/hibernate-ehcache-3.3.2.GA.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/hibernate-entitymanager-3.4.0.GA.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/httpclient-4.2.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/httpcore-4.2.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/ibmjceprovider-8.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/ibmpkcs-8.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/imaging-01012005.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/javax.persistence-2.0.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/javolution-5.5.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/jcaptcha-1.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/jcaptcha-api-1.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/jcifs-1.2.6.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/jcommon-1.0.15.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/jetty-6.1.26.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/jetty-client-6.1.26.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/jetty-embedded-6.1.26.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/jfreechart-1.0.13.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/jradius-client-20040211.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/jta-1.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/jtidy-r8-20060801.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/junit-4.8.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/log4j-1.2.14.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/mail-1.4.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/mibble-2.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/mibble-mibs-2.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/mockito-all-1.9.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/poi-3.2-FINAL.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/selenium-android-driver-2.31.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/selenium-api-2.31.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/selenium-chrome-driver-2.31.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/selenium-firefox-driver-2.31.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/selenium-htmlunit-driver-2.31.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/selenium-ie-driver-2.31.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/selenium-iphone-driver-2.31.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/selenium-java-2.31.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/selenium-remote-driver-2.31.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/selenium-safari-driver-2.31.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/selenium-server-2.31.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/selenium-support-2.31.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/servlet-api-2.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/snmp4j-2.0.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/snmp4j-agent-2.0.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/spring-aop-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/spring-asm-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/spring-beans-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/spring-context-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/spring-context-support-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/spring-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/spring-expression-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/spring-jdbc-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/spring-ldap-core-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/spring-orm-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/spring-oxm-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/spring-security-acl-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/spring-security-config-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/spring-security-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/spring-security-ldap-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/spring-security-taglibs-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/spring-test-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/spring-tx-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/spring-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/spring-webmvc-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/spring-ws-core-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/spring-ws-security-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/spring-xml-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/wsdl4j-1.6.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/wss4j-1.6.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/xmlschema-core-2.0.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/vkp/xmlsec-1.5.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

DurationAgent.java file

```
package org.springframework.aop.framework;     
import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;

public class DurationAgent {

    // for all the class loaded, premain will be called
    public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) {
        System.out.println("Executing premain.........");
        inst.addTransformer(new JavassistApplicationContext());
    }
}
```

JavassistApplicationContext.java file

```
package org.springframework.aop.framework;

import javassist.ClassPool;
import javassist.CtClass;
import javassist.CtConstructor;
import javassist.LoaderClassPath;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer;
import java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException;
import java.security.ProtectionDomain;

public class JavassistApplicationContext extends XmlWebApplicationContext implements ClassFileTransformer {

    public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className,
            Class classBeingRedefined, ProtectionDomain protectionDomain,
            byte[] classfileBuffer) throws IllegalClassFormatException {

        byte[] byteCode = classfileBuffer;
        System.out.println("Instrumenting......");
        ClassPool classPool = ClassPool.getDefault();
        try {
            ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
            classPool.appendClassPath(new LoaderClassPath(classLoader));

            CtClass cc = classPool.get("org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyCreatorSupport");
            CtConstructor c = cc.getConstructors()[0];
            c.insertAfter("$0.aopProxyFactory = new org.springframework.aop.framework.JavassistAopProxyFactory();");
            //cc.toClass();
            byteCode = cc.toBytecode();
            cc.detach();
            System.out.println("Instrumentation complete.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    return byteCode;
    }
}
```

I have build with eclipse and i got class files . After that i created instrumentation jar file with command `jar cvfm instrumentation.jar ..\meta-inf\manifest.mf .`

Now i run the file with javassit library with java agent

```
java -cp .;/lib/javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar; -javaagent:./bin/instrumentation.jar org.springframework.aop.framework.TestInstrumentation
```

and also i have tried with

```
java -cp .;/lib/javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar;/lib/spring-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar; -javaagent:./bin/instrumentation.jar org.springframework.aop.framework.TestInstrumentation
```

but still i am getting exceptions .

### This is the error stack trace :

```
Executing premain.........
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(Unknown Source)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/context/support/XmlWebApplication
Context
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.DurationAgent.premain(DurationAgent.java:10)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicati
onContext
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 19 more
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed
```

Any suggestions ? anything i am doing wrong ? please help

### update

After removing extends XmlWebApplicationContext from the code and run with

```
java -cp .;/lib/javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar -javaagent:./bin/instrumentation.jar org.springframework.aop.framework.TestInstrumentation
```

getting error on javassit :

```
Executing premain.........
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(Unknown Source)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist/ClassPath
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.DurationAgent.premain(DurationAgent.java:10)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javassist.ClassPath
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed
```

Comment: I haven't played with javaagent before, but it seems that you need to include all the required jar files in your command line for `-cp` in order to find the necessary 3rd party libraries.

Comment: I already have done with `-cp` command .

Comment: `org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext` is from spring-web jar . so i have added with `-cp` command . still getting same error

Comment: Why is your class file transformer a subclass of `XmlWebApplicationContext`?

Comment: can i do that ? i think i can . i am using for another purpose

Comment: What “another purpose” can a class file transformer have? You should adhere to the [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) for software development in general, but *especially* for Java Agents…

Comment: but at the time of `import org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext;` i am getting error . This is due to some linkage problem on jar files . but i have added all the libraries .

Comment: You have? Your `.eclipse` class path lists *tons* of libraries, your command line `-cp` option uses *two*. You should keep dependencies of Java Agents at a minimum. It is, by the way, not the `import` statement that causes any errors, as `import` statements do not exist on the byte code level. It’s the actual use, i.e. using it as the transformer’s superclass that causes the error. Since there is no reason for a class file transformer to extend this class, just remove it. You will find out that there are enough other problems with your code, so you shouldn’t waste time with the inheritance.

Comment: U updated my question after removing `XmlWebApplicationCon‌​text' . but still getting another error on javassit .

Comment: Well, *now* consider that your transformer is invoked for *every* class, not only the class you intend to transform. So the minimum you have to do, is to check the `className` and not try to transform the classes that your transformer needs itself (like `javassist.ClassPath`). When are at it, your transformer receives the correct `ClassLoader` as its first parameter, hence, you should never mess around with `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()`…